# Searching for a user

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for any advice on the way I have implemented methods (explained below). More specifically, is it a good practice or not? And if not, any suggestions?

---

> **NOTE** -   `communications.js` is used in many places throughout the app.

---

**Search_user.js**

> This code searches for cookies and returns a user object if any matches found.

---

```
function searchForAUser () {

let userName = "userName=";
let userId = "userId=";
let user = {};

let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);

let cookieArr = decodedCookie.split(';');

for(var i=0; i< cookieArr.length; i++) {
        var c = cookieArr[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === " ") {
            c= c.substring(1);
        }

        if (c.indexOf(userName) === 0) {
            let userNameDecoded =  c.substring(userName.length, c.length);          
            user.userName = userNameDecoded;
            console.log(userNameDecoded);
        }

        if (c.indexOf(userId) === 0 ) {
            var userIdDecoded = c.substring(userId.length, c.length);
            user.userId = userIdDecoded;
            console.log(user.userId);
        }
return user;
```

**main.js**

```
//used for xmlHttpRequests
let comms = require("./communications.js");
//searches a user
let serachUser = require("./search_user.js");

var main = {
    user : {},
    init : async function () {
        this.user = await searchForAUser();
        console.log(this.user);
    },

}


//verifies the user.t against a database
async function searchForAUser () {
    let user =  serachUser();
    let verify = await comms.sendUserData(user,"../../backend/Log_in.php");
    if (user.t === verify) {
        user.loggedInStatus = true;
    }
    else {
        user.loggedInStatus = false;
    }
    return user;
}
```

My question is, whether above  `searchForAUser` function is unnecessary?
And, is it good practice to use below one instead of above function?

---

> **Passing `comms` to Search_User.js**

---

**Search_User.js**

```
function searchForAUser (comms) {

let userName = "userName=";
let userId = "userId=";
let user = {};
let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);

let cookieArr = decodedCookie.split(';');

for(var i=0; i< cookieArr.length; i++) {
        var c = cookieArr[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === " ") {
            c= c.substring(1);
        }

        if (c.indexOf(userName) === 0) {
            let userNameDecoded =  c.substring(userName.length, c.length);          
            user.userName = userNameDecoded;
            console.log(userNameDecoded);
        }

        if (c.indexOf(userId) === 0 ) {
            var userIdDecoded = c.substring(userId.length, c.length);
            user.userId = userIdDecoded;
            console.log(user.userId);
        }

//communication is also done in the same function

let verify = comms.sendUserData(user,"../../backend/Log_in.php");
if (user.t === verify) {
        user.loggedInStatus = true;
    }
return user;
```

**main.js**

```
let comms = require("./communications.js");
let serachUser = require("./search_user.js");

var main = {
    user : {},
    init : async function () {
        //passing comms to the searchuser function

        this.user = searchUser(comms);
        console.log(this.user);
    },

}
```

Passing the comms method to the `searchUser` function and executing it inside the `searchUser`.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231).

Comment: @L.F. thank you for advice. I have edited and added more details. Basically I need to know is, whether passing the ````comms```` to ````searchUser```` is a good practice? I have to use more functions of this pattern throughout the app.

Comment: Are all those `console.log` statements part of your actual code? Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Mast No, ````console.log```` are only for testing purpose.

Answer (score 3):

In the matter of simplify `Search_User.js`  instead:

```
var c = cookieArr[i];
while (c.charAt(0) === " ") {
    c= c.substring(1);
}
```

you can use `trim()`

```
var c = cookieArr[i].trim();
```

and in `IF's` use `slice` or `substring` with `start` argument only

```
if (c.indexOf(userName) === 0) { user.userName = c.slice(userName.length) }
if (c.indexOf(userId) === 0) { user.userId = c.substring(userId.length) }
```